# Change "unanswered" search to "unsolved"

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, search

I generally use the filter `hasaccepted:false`, and think others do too. ([Try it with this link.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3Afalse%20closed%3Afalse%20duplicate%3Afalse%20locked%3Afalse%20hasnotice%3Afalse%20))

The clickable searches include `unanswered` which, on puzzling, may be more useful if it were `unsolved` since puzzles often get some kind of answer or answers before being solved (nearest thing filterable being `hasaccepted`).

I also note here that it is likely that newer users are generally unaware of the textual search feature, and will see and use the clickable ones.

Do people agree that we should request this?

(I actually do: `hasaccepted:false closed:false duplicate:false locked:false hasnotice:false` and am sure the tab would do something similar)

**Edit:** I agree with humn, adding `unsolved` would be preferable to changing `unanswered` to `unsolved`

Comment: Alas, the question-listing tabs are probably not made to be site-by-site  customizable except for appearance.
(I don't have the oomph to make this into an actual answer with links and evidence other than to note that
[a similar suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155001/second-level-of-ordering)
at Meta Stack Exchange in 2012 received an accepted answer that, in whimsically exaggerated terms, amounts to digital `oo1o` / Morse `..!.` / Unicode ``.)
Perhaps we can kludge something like a featured Meta Post that would always show up near `Unanswered`.

Answer (score 13):

If the suggestion is to alter the option bar for the list of questions,
I would very much like to see **unsolved** added
and would use it regularly,
but perhaps **unanswered** could be retained as well.

[image: newest | frequent | votes | active | unanswered | UNSOLVED]

All too truly, **unanswered** is useless for challenge puzzles,
which constitute the vast majority of questions here.
Nonetheless, **unanswered** still has its usual Stack Exchange purpose
to highlight sincere requests for information,
which is not only respectable in itself
but also a motivation among those who
got this site off the ground, as reflected in tags such as
[puzzle-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-theory), [puzzle-history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-history),
[puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) and [puzzle-identification](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification).

---

A related alternative is sugged here: [Improved interface to posts of common interest?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/improved-interface-to-posts-of-common-interest)

Comment: +1, I think both search can be useful, unanswered should not be deleted

Comment: It seems a little odd to have two tabs that show the exact same content under different names. Is there a difference in what would be shown between the two? (And/or how would the system automatically know?)

Comment: @Emrakul yes there is a difference in content - unsolved shows questions with no **accepted** answer (but there could be many answers) whereas unanswered only shows those with zero answers. Unanswered would be, in a naive implementation, a subset of unsolved; although I think we could filter out things like locked and such to make it most useful - see my "I actually do" note in the question. Other opinion on that would probably be helpful too.

Comment: @JonathanAllan - minor correction, "unanswered" shows questions with no *upvoted* or *accepted* answers. I.e. unanswered questions can have many answers, so long as those answers have a <1 score (not that it weakens your argument because PSE often gets upvoted partial answers or community wiki work in progress "answers").

Comment: @Alconja ah, yes ...thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm not sure the distinction between "unanswered" and "unsolved" is going to be clear enough to a new user, or even existing users who haven't seen this post. Just a thought - are there better/clearer names we could use?

Comment: @Emrakul - FWIW, note that there are tool tips on those links (unanswered currently says "Questions that have no upvoted answers", so unsolved could just say "Questions that have no accepted answer").

Comment: @Emrakul Would *open* be a better term? Or would that be too close (pun intdented) to *close* ?

Comment: Err... What exactly is the difference? I suppose everyone understands that "unanswered" accounts for the 'unsolved'

Comment: @Sid : "Unanswered" doesn't include many "unsolved" puzzles, namely those that have upvoted answers but no accepted answer.
These puzzles can quickly become scattered and lost among and behind solved newer puzzles in "newest" and "active" listings.