# Improved interface to posts of common interest?

Tags: discussion, search, user-interface

**Q:**  
What do these three recently well-received Meta posts have in common?

    
[Change “unanswered”
 search to “unsolved”](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766)

    
[Should we have a meta-sorted list of
 puzzles here on Meta?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4968)

    
[Should we implement an automated way of highlighting
 quality content?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4974)

Hint, but basically the answer:

> Ready access, including for newcomers,
>     to Puzzling posts that meet useful nonstandard criteria.

**Q:**  
How do we get Stack Exchange developers
to help us improve the site's interface?

$\color{#3c3}{\Large\checkmark\kern-4mu}$**A:**  
We don't.
They are busy rushing to accidents
and don't have time for traffic snarls.

**Q:**  
What *can* we do?

**A:**  
We can easily add a single always-[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) Meta post
that shows up near the standard search options.
This is prime interface real estate,
completely under our control,
and may be used for more than what is presented here.
The posts mentioned above could be well served
by having the title of such an ever-present post
include something like
“unsolved | other searches | curated.”

[image]

Clicking there would go to something like the following.
(Plagiarized from posts mentioned above.)

---

#### Automated searches

[Unsolved puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3afalse%20closed%3afalse%20duplicate%3afalse%20locked%3afalse%20hasnotice%3afalse)

[Popular puzzles, 2016/01](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/498543/popular-puzzles?year=2016&month=01)

[Puzzles you may have missed, 2016/01](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/498542/puzzles-you-may-have-missed?year=2016&month=01)

[Well received puzzles, 2016/01](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/498541/well-received-puzzles?year=2016&month=01)

#### Curated categories

[Puzzles that require a lot of work to solve](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/should-we-have-a-meta-sorted-list-of-puzzles-here-on-meta)

[Puzzles that are good to use in RPG adventures](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/should-we-have-a-meta-sorted-list-of-puzzles-here-on-meta)

$~\raise-1ex\vdots$

Comment: I very much like this idea. Creative hacking!

Comment: I would like to push this idea a bit. It does not seem to have gotten the attention it deserves (IMHO). Any moderators (old or new) willing to support this? (@emrakul)