# Is there a way to get the "question" style list when using a search filter?

Tags: support

> When one uses the "questions" tab on the main site, one typically gets a layout like this:

[image]
<sub>Link as: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered</sub>

> But when one starts restricting the results using the search-box (for [this reason](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/change-unanswered-search-to-unsolved)), the layout changes to:

[image]
(No user avatars, larger preview size)
<sub>Link as: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20hasaccepted%3afalse%20closed%3afalse%20duplicate%3afalse%20locked%3afalse%20hasnotice%3afalse</sub>

> ### Is there a way I can get the "questions only" layout but with additional filter-restrictions?